# Making bluetooth discoverable without user confirmation

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

In Android, there there is enable() method that seems to enable bluetooth without user confirmation. I was wondering if there is a way to enable discoverable as well programmatically without user confirmation?

Thank you very much

Comment: *... without user confirmation"* - that sounds like a bad idea to me :)

Comment: There is no such method to enable Bluetooth discoverable on  developer.android.com, I think you have to show a system activity that requests discoverable mode using `ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE`.

Comment: No its not necessarily. I want to ask user first time only and after that I don't want every time to ask him as it will be enabled and disabled on multiple paramters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The Research

I started researching for you answer by reading about the enable() method. See ["Setting Up Bluetooth"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#SettingUp) then #2. They say there:

[image]

["Enabling Discoverability"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#EnablingDiscoverability) has a lot of information that could be useful to keep your code DRY or make a workaround.

### The Answer

According to the documentation, making a device discoverable will always make a popup appear for user confirmation.

The workaround, provided by Android, is not to make the device discoverable at all:
[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer but unfortunately  that won't help. The reason is that I want the application to run on 2 devices and I will need them discoverable to be found. By each other (or at least one find the other)

Comment: Ummm... Adam has provided a well researched and accurate answer.  Fortunately for all of us Android users, it is very hard to make our devices discoverable, programmatically, without our knowledge.  The fact that this is not the answer you wanted to hear doesn't seem significant.  Come on @Snake, do the right thing: accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: G.Blake, I appreciate Adam research it's not about that the answer is not what I wanted to hear, it is that it does not answer the question. It may be fortunate for users the this "might" not be possible but it also could stop creative ideas where things need to be automated and not stoppable by user input. One time permission from the app shouldve been Suffient.. Anyways, I am updating the answer because of the effort put into it

Comment: I appreciate the conversation and would love for you to have a workaround. I understand not accepting it currently, because it might detract attention from someone with a functional fix. However, if that fix doesn't come or I turn out to be correct, please consider accepting my answer. Thanks for posting the question.

Comment: Since no other answers has been submitted, I will accept this answer as closest :)

Comment: Thanks @Snake! Appreciate your integrity.

Comment: Actually I think it is possible. You can estabilish an insecure connection to a bluetooth device, if you already know its address (e.g. by previous pairing; or, if you want to connect two specific devices, you can set their addresses in a configuration file)